# Modernizr doesn't check for cssresize

Tags: resize, modernizr

I'm learning to use modernizr. The documentation says it checks for resize attribute and it returns a cssresize class if that feature is supported, or a no-cssresize feature if it's not.

It returns neither value in the list of classes assigned to the html element.

To get the modernizr js file, I clicked on every single option on the download page.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't know the answer to the question, but I found a workaround that acts like Modernizr says it does.

    if (document.body.style.resize !== undefined) {
        html.classList.add("cssresize");
    } else {
        html.classList.add("no-cssresize");
    }


Putting that script in my start-up javascript meant all the code I wrote expecting Modernizr to do it's job worked fine.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of formatting on the code, I tried to understand the instructions and tried repeatedly to get it to format correctly, until the system timed out further edits.